# Ubuntu wifi roaming problem: how do I set wireless sensitivity on ubuntu?

Tags: wireless

I am having problem with wifi network that have multiple access points. ubuntu keeps roaming between access points because of high sensitivity.  Based on reading the manual for iwconfig, there is an option to set sensitivity like `iwconfig wlan0 sens -80`. This keeps failing with operation not permitted. So I want to know if there is a way, to set the sensitivity of roaming in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I think the better way to approach that problem is to run:

```
nm-tool
```

Find the MAC address for the access point you want with the highest signal strength. Then Edit Connections in Network manager to tell NM that is the MAC, also known as BSSID, you want. Please see attached. It should then stay on that MAC and not roam to others.[image]

Comment: Hmm, how can I figure out which access point is best. The problem is on mac it does not have a problem. Only ubuntu, fyi, I am running dual boot on macbook pro.

Comment: Open a terminal and run the command: nm-tool. At the end, there will be a list of wireless access points listing the strength and MAC address among other details. Pick the network you prefer, and select the specific listing with the best strength. Put its MAC address in 'BSSID' as above.

Comment: Oh, sorry I did not realize it lists all access points. I will give it a try and report back. But just in case, is there a way to change the sens parameter? Thanks.

Comment: After some tests, it seems ubuntu refuses to connect to the access point with highest signal that brodcast on channel 11. I installed wicd and tried through the gui after stoping network manager and I confirm that ubuntu refuses to connect to the access point on channel 11. Possibly related to [this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/931168)

Comment: Is that your wireless card as listed in lspci -nn? 14e4:4727? I doubt you are using the same driver. wl is preferred. On some cards, sens is not adjustable. Check: iwlist wlan0 event. If your wireless interface is eth1, then iwlist eth1 event.

Comment: My driver is `Broadcom Corporation BCM4331 802.11a/b/g/n` on Macbook pro 8,1 and wireless interface is wlan0. This is driving me crazy because it works fine at home with only one access point.

Comment: Did you fill in the MAC in the form I used above? Colons, capital letters, etc.? Wicd is supposed to work better in these cases but you'll probably need to remove Network manager altogether.

Comment: I put the address as you describe in your snapshot. It saves it but ignores it. Meaning, when i put the mac address of the access point, then run iwconfig, or nm-tool, I see that I'm connected to a different access point (mac address). With Wicd, when I try to connect to the said access point, it just keeps trying but fails to connect. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Did you also fill in the encryption details?

Comment: I don't think there is any encryption. Here is the output of nm-tool `Infra, 00:24:6C:80:D7:40, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 64`. This is the one that Ubuntu refuses to connect to.

Comment: Correct; there is no encryption. Can you try to connect to it and post your log to pastebin? cat /var/log/syslog | grep etwork | tail -n20. Paste it here and give us the link. http://paste.ubuntu.com/

Comment: [Here it is](http://pastebin.com/e5324Z0m). thanks a lot. For now I am going to give up and boot in mac os.

Comment: It seems that the problem is only with this particular network. I am not the only one. Mac and Windows connect fine but ubuntu, regardless of hardware, have problems connecting to this particular network. What could be the issue so at least I can talk to the network guys?

Comment: If it were a home router, I might try disabling N speeds. I have no other suggestions.

Comment: Thank you for your help. One last thing when I do iwconfig, i see ` wlan0 IEEE 802.11b/g` could this be the problem
? if so do you know how i enable the n ?

Comment: I think it's related. Either your hardware does N or it doesn't. I don't believe you can enable it in software. A number of Linux drivers are still troubled by N and we solve a lot of problems turning off N at the driver, the router or both. I thought we might tinker with the driver parameters from modinfo wl (or whatever your driver is), however, if this is a common problem in Ubuntu and Linux generally, it seems unlikely to be a driver issue since not all Linux computers use the same wireless driver. It could also be a Network Manager problem.

Comment: This doesn't work. Initially it connects to the correct AP, but couple minutes later is uses the wrong AP again.

Comment: @Grant Rather than tag on to this ancient dead question, I suggest you start your own new question.

Comment: @chili555 Thank you for your suggestion. I already foud a different solution - using wpa_cli blacklist <BSSID>.